# How to add SharePoint as a data source when creating a web part?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, datasource

I have created a web part in VS 2010 using the web part template. Now I am trying to add my sharepoint server as a data source for some controls but SharePoint does NOT show up in the Data Source Configuration Wizard. Only thing that shows up is XML script.

When I click on "Data" in the menu bar, only options are  "schema compare", "Data Compare", "Transact-SQL Editor", and "Schema View"

How can I get SharePoint to show up in the Wizard?